# Convert Crystal Report Expression to SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports, ssrs-2012

How can I change the below Crystal Report Expression to SQL Server Query Case Statement  ? Any help appreciated.

AvgLbsPerWeek

```
If {@EnoughWeightsSum} < {@FreqForCalcs} then 
    (AvgLbsPerWeek := AvgLbsPerWeek +0;
       0;)  
else If {@EnoughWeightsSum} >= {@FreqForCalcs} then
    (AvgLbsPerWeek := AvgLbsPerWeek +{@AvgByDaySum}/{@EnoughWeightsSum}*{@FreqForCalcs};
       {@AvgByDaySum}/{@EnoughWeightsSum}*{@FreqForCalcs};)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple CASE statement

```
SELECT 
  AvgLbsPerWeek = 
    CASE WHEN @EnoughWeightSum < @FreqForCalcs
        THEN AvgPoundsPerWeek
    ELSE 
         AvgPoundsPerWeek + @AvgByDaySum/(@EnoughWeightSum*FreqForCalcs)
             -- I didn't quite understand how the last code fit in
    END
 FROM Table
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm not following.  If you create a schema and desired results, it will be easier to help